# Email triggers?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, automation

Does anyone know of a way to use an email as a trigger to send another email?

I would like to setup a rule that will send me an email wi a specific body hand subject if I receive an email from user X with subject Y and body Z. The email that I want to send out would ideally be to recipient A, with body B and subject C. Is this possible? Doesn't look supported in Outlook but I am ok using other tools...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a little VBA:

1. Press Alt + F11 to open the VBA editor.
2. Open Microsoft Outlook Objects
3. Click on ThisOutlookSession
4. Enter this code

   ```
   Sub SendEmailToPerson(Item As Outlook.MailItem)

   Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application
   Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
   Set myItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

   myItem.Body = "Scripted body"
   myItem.Subject = "Scripted Subject"
   myItem.Recipients.Add ("person@email.com")

   myItem.Send
   ```

End Sub

Now in your Rule you need to 'Run a script' and point to this script.

Here are some more examples:

http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/run-script-rule-change-subject-message/