# Outlook 2010 create rule

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

I am using Outlook 2010. Is it possible to create a rule that resembles the following: When I receive a message with specific subject schedule 5 emails (1st reply-immediately, 2nd-after 3 hours, 3rd - after 6 hours etc..)?

Comment: I don't think so, sorry. Not time delayed. immediate yes. However you might be able to write script (e.g. batch) and use "run application" and pass arguments to the batch file, but that's quite advanced; and you'll be stuck with cmd window open until it finishes executing

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script.

The VBA would look something like this.

```
Sub MultipleDelayedReplies(MyMail As MailItem)

Dim HourInc As Integer
Dim sEndDate As Date

Dim reply As MailItem
Dim i As Integer

sEndDate = Now()

reply.Subject = reply.Subject & " Immediate Reply."
reply.HTMLBody = "Reply 1" & reply.HTMLBody

HourInc = 3

For i = 2 To 5

    Set reply = MyMail.reply

    sEndDate = DateAdd("h", HourInc, sEndDate)

    reply.DeferredDeliveryTime = sEndDate
    reply.Subject = reply.Subject & " " & reply.DeferredDeliveryTime
    reply.HTMLBody = "Reply " & i & reply.HTMLBody

    'reply.Display
    ' or
    reply.Send

Next i

End Sub
```

The process is further described here.

[Email triggers?](https://superuser.com/questions/495474/email-triggers)

I believe Outlook has to be on to send the emails at the designated times.